# Using IPFS inside a Vagrant box

Tags: vagrant, ipfs

I am trying to access IPFS webui (http://localhost:5001/webui) and the hashes of the the files added to IPFS via my local node (https://localhost:8080/ipfs/HASH_OF_MY_FILE) and seem to be failing. But with the URL https://gateway.ipfs.io/ipfs/HASH_OF_MY_FILE it seems to be working, though webui is meant for the local node and does not seem to be working. I know that servers running inside Vagrant must be run on 0.0.0.0 to be accessible on the host machine but I am not able to figure it out for IPFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure IPFS with this command `ipfs config Addresses.Gateway /ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/8080`

And then restart the daemon. `ipfs daemon`